Inconsistent Results with KStream-KTable Join Under Load
I'm developing a Quarkus microservice that utilizes Kafka Streams to process messages from multiple topics.
Specifically, I'm attempting to join a KStream and a KTable derived from two of these topics.
Under normal conditions, the join operates as expected. However, under increased load, the join occasionally fails to produce results, even though both messages appear to be processed, but the ones from the KTable seems to be processed slightly after the ones of the KStream(even if the actual timestamp of the produced message is before).
Code Example:
KStream<String, OperationAvro> operationKStream = streamsBuilder.stream(operationTopic);
KStream<String, ContextAvro> contextKStream = streamsBuilder.stream(contextTopic);
KTable<String, ContextAvro> contextKTable = contextKStream.toTable(Materialized.as(contextStoreName));

// both KTable and KStream use a custom processor which logs each message and its timestamp

KStream<String, Result> processingResultStream = operationKStream
    .filter((key, value) -> isEligible(value))
    .join(
        contextKTable,
        (operation, context) -> topicsJoiner(operation, context),
        Joined.with(Serdes.String(), new ValueAndTraceSerde<>(getSpecificAvroSerde()), getSpecificAvroSerde())
    )
    .peek(this::logTheOutputOfJoiner)
    .mapValues(handler::processTheJoinedData);


Issue:

Under normal load, the join between operationKStream and contextKTable functions correctly.
Under higher load, there are instances where the join does not produce results, because when the KStream's message is processed, the corresponding KTable's message is not yet present, even if it is actually already sent from the producer.
Note: when the KTable's message is processed and logged(after the join was tried and skipped), the timestamp of it(attached by the producer when the message was created) is before the timestamp of the corresponding message from the KSTream.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Checked Partition Assignment: Ensured that messages with the same key are assigned to the same partition across topics to facilitate correct joining(co-partitioning).
Adjusted num.stream.threads: Set to 6 as all the topics I'm subscribed to have 6 partitions. This didn't solve the issue as the messages with the same key will be distributed to the same stream task which is on a single thread for co-partitioning.
Adjusted max.task.idle.ms: Set to 2000 ms to allow for out-of-order message handling(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-353%3A+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization). This did not resolve the issue.

My question is why this issue happen as the timestamp of the messages seems to be in correct order, but it happen for the messages from the KStream to be processed before the ones of KTable, which make the join to be skipped.

I would recommend to use Kafka Streams 3.6+ which adds a new "grace period" to stream-table joins (set via Joined parameter) which allows you to "delay" the table lookup to ensure that all KTable data is loaded. Using this feature requires to use "versioned state stores" (added in 3.5 release) for the join-KTable.
Also compare the docs:

https://kafka.apache.org/39/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-ktable-join
https://kafka.apache.org/39/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#versioned-state-stores
https://kafka.apache.org/39/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#versioned-state-stores

